# grabbing text in div with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
  <a class="source" href="jquery-lead.php?source=<?=$src;?>">3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.source").live('click', function() { 
        $("#results").load(this.href, { page: $(this).text() });
      return false;
    });
    $("a.source:first").click()
</script>
```

I am able to pass $src variable to my php script, but I also want to pass whatever is in the  tag. In this case "3", this is going to be a pagination..

Comment: People will be more inclined to help if you go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: @vick - @Oren's correct - There are many benefits: you get rep, the answerer gets rep, your questions are much more appealing to answer, meaning you get quicker answers) and the next person finding this gets to the correct answer quicker.

Comment: No Vick.  Not "next time".  You SHOULD accept answers NOW. Go to your user-page: http://stackoverflow.com/users/305360/vick, go through your 14 previous questions, and mark at least some answers as "Accepted".

Comment: I had no idea I had to accept questions, I will do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated for comments** - You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.source").live('click', function() { 
    $("#results").load(this.href, { page: $(this).text() });
    return false;
  });
  $("a.source:first").click();
});
```

This uses [`.load(url, data)`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), in your php the `page` variable will now be available...or whatever you want it called, just rename appropriately.

Comment: its sends page as a POST and not GET, what are the differences? Should I try to stick with GET on both variables or it makes no difference?

Comment: @vick - I'd have a read here for the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get  As for the other...up to you, what does that `source` variable look like?

Comment: ok thanks nick.
I am also wondering is there a way to automatically call the first link in the paginator?

<a class="source" href="jquery-lead.php?src=<?=$src;?>">1</a></div>

Comment: @vick - `$("a.source:first").click()` would execute the handler for it.

Comment: @vick - You have to tell me what the error/behavior is to answer that...also I would go accept answers on your questions, with 0 chance on reward, there's not much motivation for anyone to help...

Comment: Nick: Its not loading the first page, I still have to click on the first link to get something to load.

Comment: @vick - Make sure you put that code **after** the code above, you want the click handler attached before triggering the event.

Comment: Look at the new code above, that is how it is now...still not calling the first link :(

Comment: @vick - Ah you're missing a `document.ready` wrapper, so the code doesn't execute until the `<a>` exists to find.  Look at the updated answer above for how to wrap it so it'll execute on `document.ready`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).text();
```