# How check text in span?

Tags: jquery, html

I have html code:

```
<span id="gruszka1">1</span>
```

I found solution to check if that specific span exist:

```
if($('span#gruszka1').length){
//do something
});
```

Now I would like check if span#gruszka1.text is equal to 1 then script do something. How code should look?

Comment: You know, a *basic* search on jQuery docs would give you that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [grabbing text in div with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725686/grabbing-text-in-div-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How code should look:

```
if ($("#gruszka1").text() == "1")
{
    // do something
}
```

---

You don't have to use this selector: `span#gruszka1`. **#gruszka1** should be unique on the page so writing `#gruszka1` should be sufficient.

---

[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

Comment: Since you're comparing text (strings), it is recommended to use the `===` operator instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery's [Text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span#gruszka1').text();
```

Will give you the text contained in the element.

```
var $span = $('#gruszka1');

if( $span.length ) {

  if( $span.text() == '1' ) {

    // do something

  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check that's `1` but you don't care about filling this field with other things than numbers, what about:

```
if($("span#gruszka1").text().trim() == "1")
{
   // TODO: Further actions
}
```

If you need to check that has numbers only and one digit, you'll need to use regular expressions this way:

```
if(new RegExp("[0-9]").test($("span#gruszka1").text().trim()) && $("span#gruszka1").text().trim() == "1")
{
    // TODO: Further actions
}
```